# Serialized data for requesting a Date value are different for JSON and XML

Tags: java, jersey, jackson

I have a Jersey Rest service that leverages the Jackson annotations to perform the serialization/deserialization for my service

but when jersey/jackson serializes my object with the below field i get two different values for the result for XML vs JSON requests

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private Date startDate;
```

Results

```
JSON: "startDate": "2016-02-01"

XML: <startDate>2016-02-01T00:00:00-05:00</startDate>
```

the json is showing correctly, but the XML results give all sorts of stuff I dont want at the end.

I've tried using other suggestions like

```
JsonSerializer<T> and JsonDeserializer<T>
```

but it gives me the same incorrect results

Am I missing an annotation to specifically handle XML?